# Gradle resValue causes duplicate string resources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My Android manifest file defines the app name as follows:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

A corresponding entry for app_name exists in res/values/strings.xml

Now, in my build.gradle, I redefine the app name for beta build as follows:

```
buildTypes {

    beta {
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        debuggable true
        resValue "string", "app_name", "MyTest Beta"
    }
}
```

However, when I assemble the package, Gradle complains of a duplicate string resource.

I could simply remove the app_name token from string.xml. However, in that case, Android Studio reports a problem with the manifest file.

How do I fix this? Regards.

Comment: did you try "alias"? `<string name="app_name">@string/app_name_alias</string>` in xml  and `resValue "string", "app_name_alias", "MyTest Beta"` in gradle (android studio will showing "an error" in resources but this should at least compile

Comment: As a simple solution, after removing the string from `strings.xml` and adding it as a `resValue` in gradle call Build -> Clean Project. After that call Build -> Make Project. The problem with manifest should gone

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shouldn't have to mess with a 'resValue.' You can use the debug sourceset which will allow you to redefine other strings in debug as well. Create the following file and redefine the 'app_name' string in there.

```
src/debug/res/values/strings.xml
```

Just make sure you don't have anything like the following in your build.gradle's sourceSets

```
debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
```

Answer (score 9):

I came across the same issue too. 
My solution is to use `Manifest-placeholder`.

```
<application
    android:label="${APP_NAME}"
    tools:replace="android:label">
```

In your `defaultConfig` closure, set the value

```
defaultConfig {
    addManifestPlaceholders([APP_NAME: "@string/app_name"])
}
```

And Change that value in your flavors.

```
buildTypes {
    beta {
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        debuggable true
        addManifestPlaceholders([APP_NAME: "MyTest Beta"])
    }
}
```

Drawback:

- HardCode appName in flavor. (which may or may not be a deal)

To fix that drawback, you can combine `Manifest-placeholder` and `resValue`, which is to create a resource use `resValue` and to change `android:label` to your resource.

Comment: What's the importance of tools:replace="android:label"?