# resValue in android Gradle - does resValue override string with same name

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In the android `build.gradle` file I want to try a resValue defined in a flavor like this:

```
resValue "string", "suffix", "- Pro"
```

but in `strings.xml` I already have a string called "suffix" defined and it's also localized to other strings.

I want to know if I define this in my `build.gradle` file will it override the ones in any `strings.xml` file or just the default one, etc? What takes precedence `resValue` or `strings.xml`?

Comment: you can just try it and check the `build` folder, all those resources get generated there

Comment: Did you try to build?  Pretty sure your trying to define the same variable twice and the build should fail.  For reference:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32260563/873237