# Duplicate Resources Error with generated files in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: [string/app_name] C:\Android Work\projectName\build\generated\res\resValues\tst\values\generated.xml   [string/app_name] C:\Android Work\projectName\build\generated\res\resValues\tst\values\gradleResValues.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

Same file is in generated.xml and gradleResValues.xml

```
<!-- Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY -->

<!-- Values from build type: tst -->
<string name="app_name" translatable="false">Test</string>
```

It's saying there's a same string in these both files, how to avoid this exception?

By the way it's only happening to my test build, debug build is working fine!!

Comment: You can't delete one of them?

Comment: it's recreating

Comment: File>invalidate caches Have you tried this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle resValue causes duplicate string resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259741/gradle-resvalue-causes-duplicate-string-resources)

Comment: no, i don't have any app_name in strings.xml and debug.setRoot('build-types/debug') is not defined in my build file. Yes, I have tried Invalidate and restart. no result.

Comment: @SaiVihari Were you able to find a solution for this?